# How to do incremental backup to archive files at destination sub-folders

Tags: linux, backup, archive, rsync

i am using debian. i need to run daily incremental backup for files that are modified since last backup. this is local backup from one disk to another in same system.

- directory structure will be same as source
- each folder and subfolder has its own compressed archive containing files-only
- on first backup, folder structure will be made as source, and files will be archived
- on each subsequent backup, newly created folders will be created and new files will be archived to destination. files modified since last backup, will be updated into relevant archive in destination.

is it possible with rsync on any other efficient method?? please help.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is possible.  Use rsync with the -z option in a cron job.  You would might have to loop over files with a shell script to get the directory structure you described.  Your question is really too broad though, you should tell us what you tried, what you want, and why it didn't work.  I could figure it out, but I'm not here to write your code for you.

Comment: the structure illustrated above is just an example to sketch my requirement. i did this on windows using vb.net. iterated recursively  through folders of source drive and modified previous archives using update option in pkzip-shell. I am new to linux. i tried rsync command options but could not figure out how to write a script to iterate through folders and update previous backup archives.  a script example will be really helpful.